# Merge data from two DAO into one TO

Tags: java, web-services, dao, dto

I have a siutation where I want to work with one business object (TO). However the data that this TO consist of comes from 2 different data sources:

- The application's database, which will be accessed through JPA and one Entity
- An old system's data, which will be accessed through a Webservice

In later phases of this project, all the data will be moved into the application's database. Therefore I want to have one business object (TO) to represent all this data.

My approach is one of the following:

1) Have a DAO for the Entity and another DAO for the Old System. Then yet another DAO on top of these, which will create the Business Object that I want to use in the rest of the application.

2) Have only one DAO that will retrieve some data from the Entity and some from the Old System.

What's your thoughts about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to introduce a service layer on top of `Dao's` (Entity, Old system) and inject (assuming you're using `Spring`) all the `Dao's` into the service. Option 1 is better however just create two Dao's inside a Service and create the Business Transfer Object that will be used throughout the application.
The workflow would be UI -> PersonService -> Dao1 (app db), Dao2(Webservice). The PersonService will have the necessary business logic if any. Additionally, you can create a PersonDaoFactory inside the PersonService to abstract the creation of Dao's inside Service layer. So, at the end we will have something like below from the Controller or UI Layer(an hypothetical scenario as i do not know the domain model):

```
Person person = personService.findUserById(personId);
Product product = person.getProducts();
Comment comment = person.getComments();
Friends friends = person.getFriends();
```

Additionally, Think of a problem that many DAO solve and one big DAO would not solve.

Comment: Unfortunately Spring won't be used.

Comment: Ok, So I would have a Service Layer on top of my Data Access Layer (the DAO: s)? If I have a PersonEntity and a PersonEntityDAO (for the application's data) and a PersonOldSystemDAO, what should the object on top be called if not a DAO?

Comment: Yes. The workflow would be UI -> PersonService -> Dao1 (app db), Dao2(Webservice). The PersonService will have the necessary business logic if any.

Comment: I might be getting into another topic here, but I thought the Business Layer/Service Layer only should contain Business Logic and expose webservices? So isn't this MergeObject supposed to be in a layer below that?

Comment: It is upto you on where to merge but why add that extra layer when you can do the same in Service layer

Comment: Is the Business Layer and the Service Layer the same thing? Or two different layers where the Business Layer contains the business logic and the Service Layer contains for instance the PersonService and others?

How about Webservices? If those above mentioned layers are different layers, the webservices could reside in both layers?

Comment: Difference would be that Business layer contain business logic whereas Service layer just exposes the underlying API to be consumed by UI layer. SO, Service Layer --> Business Layer --> Dao. However, sometimes you have to make a call if you want to over-engineer your architecture or keep it simple. Check out the diagram presented here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658124.aspx

Comment: So in your example above "UI -> PersonService -> Dao1 (app db), Dao2(Webservice)", where is the Business Layer?

Comment: I had combined the Service and business layer.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty difficult to answer that without an idea of the data. 
What I would do is to have two dao's :one for the db and one for the webservice (I would call it more a service than a dao) and use the latter to add properties to the entity retrieve by the JPA dao. 
I would later drop the service/dao of webservice and evolve the JPA dao.

And as stated by the other answer, you would need to abstract this by using theses dao's from a service. 
Therefore your first solution sounds better to me.